# Web api controller initializing object though its json not in web api request. Why?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

The android device is sending the request to my webapi method:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage ProfileManagement(Profile objProfile)
        {
            objProfile = objRepository.ProfileManagement(objProfile);
            if (objProfile == null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, Resources.Messages.UnsuccessfulProfileUpdate);
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, objProfile);
        }
```

Request url is :`http://myserver:50000/api/webapi/ProfileManagement`
Requested data is :

```
{
  "objCompanyContact": {
    "Address": "",
    "City": "",
    "CompanyName": "",
    "CountryId": "0",
    "Emaild": "",
    "Fax": "",
    "Id": "327",
    "Logo": "",
    "LogoPath": "",
    "MobileNumber": "",
    "PhoneNumber": "",
    "PostCode": "",
    "StateId": "0"
  },
  "objVATCIS": {
    "CIS": "True",
    "CISNumber": "1234",
    "IsActive": "False",
    "IsVATRegistered": "True",
    "MembershipNo": "44444",
    "OtherTrade": "Joiner",
    "OtherTradeOrg": "N.I.C.F.",
    "SchemeId": "3",
    "TradeId": "3",
    "TradeOrganisationId": "27",
    "VATNumber": "1234",
    "VatRate": "5"
  }
}
```

Where following is my Profile object:

```
public class Profile
    {
        public Profile()
        {
            this.objCompanyContact = new CompanyContact();
            this.objRatesLiability = new RatesLiability();
            this.objVATCIS = new VATCIS();
            this.objUserInformation = new UserInformation();
        }

        public CompanyContact objCompanyContact { get; set; }
        public RatesLiability objRatesLiability { get; set; }
        public VATCIS objVATCIS { get; set; }
        public UserInformation objUserInformation { get; set; }
    }
```

If observing the Request json body there is data present for only objCompanyContact ,objVATCIS which are user define class properties in profile class.

When this request triggers to web api method. it initializes all 4 properties. where objRatesLiability,objUserInformation properties internal values are null. Question is if web request not providing the json body for  objRatesLiability & objUserInformation then why should it initializing those?

Comment: The constructor in `Profile` initialises all the properties not web API.

Comment: That is perfect. but look at this line  public HttpResponseMessage ProfileManagement(Profile objProfile) Here there is no call for constructor. this means it is not allocating space for internal properties.

Comment: I don't no what you mean by "it is not allocating space for internal properties". The model binder has to create an instance of `Profile` somehow, it does so by calling the default constructor. A class used as a parameter in a web API controller does not have a default constructor will cause an exception.